# Primary Constructor + Call Super Constructor in Kotlin

Tags: inheritance, kotlin, constructor

```
open class Foo constructor(a: Int) {
    private val _a: Int = a
}

open class Bar : Foo {
    constructor(a: Int, b: Int) : super(a) {
        // doSomething
    }
    constructor(a: Int, b: String) : super(a) {
        // doSomething
    }
}
```

I want to make 'constructor(a: Int, b: Int)' of 'Bar' class as the primary constructor, calling the constructor of super class. How can write it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your primary constructor like normal and use its parameters to "invoke" a constructor of inherited class. Then move your primary constructor logic into a `init` block:

```
open class Bar(a: Int, b: Int) : Foo(a) {
    init {
        // [1] init block serves as primary constructor body
    }

    constructor(a: Int, b: String) : this(a, b.toInt()) {
        // [2] doSomething
    }
}
```

This will however impose following constraints:

1. Secondary constructor must call into primary constructor. This means you must be able to transform arguments or provide default values to it if needed.
2. Both constructor and init blocks will be invoked (in that order: [1] and [2]).
3. You're limiting your class to use only a single constructor from parent class. If it has more than one constructor and you want to match & call them in your child class you can not use a primary constructor.